# add external project to web site wordpress on production

Tags: posts, customization

I have a website in wordpress that I just migrated to an ubuntu server, what I need to do is add a project developed with laravel that will be the section to make purchases for example www.example.com/store.

I have the doubt, I can create a file as a template page.php and from there add the index of my new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't touch Laravel recently. I hope my idea will help you.

First of all, in general you can't run Laravel app using of Wordpress's wheel because of differences of mechanism and structure for each one.

Second, let's think that you have two domains and one points wp and another points laravel app. Then you can set redirect wp's /store page to laravel app's domain.

Third, if you are an advanced laravel user, you might be able to point public folder of laravel app to your wp's store folder. But what's the benefit of this instead of using 2nd idea.

Fourth, how about making web app and that uses Laravel's api? I suppose this will be good solution.

Comment: hello and thanks for the help.

What happens is the following, in my work they have a website running www.exmaple.com, the store developed it independently and what they want me to do is have that folder of the new project add it to the server / var / www / html , where are the wordpress files.
The question is how to point to that folder or php files in this case the index of the store so that when writing www.exmaple./store show me the project developed independently.

Comment: Just put the store app in a /store folder, then you can just link to /store. You don't need to do anything in WordPress.